# How to filter Data table

Tags: c#, vb.net, datatables

I want to filter  data table based on some condition .

I have a data table like that

```
        Tabel A
 MobileNo     Email 
 9999999999   test@test1.com
 8888888888   test@test2.com
 9999999999   test@test5.com
 7777777777   test@test6.com
```

I want to get distinct value based on mobile also  I need data that not exits in distinct table  but table A have
Like

```
 
  Distinct Table                                          Ignore Table
  MobileNo     Email                                MobileNo     Email 
 9999999999   test@test1.com                        9999999999   test@test5.com
 8888888888   test@test2.com
 7777777777   test@test6.com
```

I have also tried googling but that are not very much understandable.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How do you decide which one of 9999999999's email addresses you want to ignore?

Comment: What does the representation of the data look like in code?

Comment: I just give a reference . whatever i want to get distinct and ignore data

Comment: I  get distinct  data but really I stuck how to get Ignored rows 
            Dim ValidData = (From row In tbValid.AsEnumerable()
                          Let Mobile = row.Field(Of String)("Mobile")
                          Group row By Mobile Into DupMobile = Group
                          Select DupMobile.First).ToArray

Comment: You can use Linq like : Dim results = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(function(x) x.Field(Of integer)("MobileNo") = 9999999999).CopyToDatatable()

Comment: It looks like you need to join two tables.  Download the Linq examples and look at the join statements. : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Sample-Queries-Visual-Basic-fc261c03

Answer (score 0):

You can use the select method on DataTable

```
Dim dtFiltered As New DataTable()
dtFiltered = dtAllData.DefaultView.ToTable(True, "MobileNo")
```

dtAllData is the DataTable containing all records
dtFiltered contains only Distinct Records

For more details check [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

**UPDATE** based on your comment
In that case you need to use except as in 
[datatable-comparison-using-linq-except-intersect-union](http://dotnetmentors.com/adonet/datatable-comparison-using-linq-except-intersect-union.aspx)

From all records extract distinct records to second DataTable and then use Except to compare the first and second DataTable

Comment: I get distinct data but really I stuck how to get Ignored rows 
            Dim ValidData = (From row In tbValid.AsEnumerable()
                          Let Mobile = row.Field(Of String)("Mobile")
                          Group row By Mobile Into DupMobile = Group
                          Select DupMobile.First).ToArray

Comment: Thanks . its help me to understand .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help

Finally I got the solution

```
    Dim ValidData = (From row In tbValid.AsEnumerable()
                          Let Mobile = row.Field(Of String)("Mobile")
                          Group row By Mobile Into DupMobile = Group
                          Select DupMobile.First).ToArray

     Dim Ignoredata = tbValid.AsEnumerable().Except(ValidData.AsEnumerable(), DataRowComparer.Default).ToArray
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example all you have done is order your mobile no. in desending order which means you could then create a SQL to say something like: ORDER BY MobileNo DESC at the end of the statement. At least it will display the same way

Or are you meaning:

```
Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(DataTable.DataView)
dv.RowFilter = "%" &...
```